# How would I create a more dynamic uniform shader?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to create a uniform buffer object (UBO), and I need to fill the array with uniforms. The way I am currently doing it is with a hard coded structure.

```
[Serializable,StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct MaterialBlock
        {
            private Vector4 uniform;
        };
```

Then I use Marshaling to get the byte array from that structure, and I fill my UBO with that array.

```
public void SetUniformShader(MaterialBlock block, int count) {
            int maxSizeMaterialUniformBuffer;
            int sizeMaterialBlock = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (MaterialBlock));
            int sizeUniformInstance = sizeMaterialBlock*count;
            int uniformInstancesPerBlock;
            int numberOfBlocks;
            int activeUniformBlocks;
            byte[] mtlBuffer;
            int uniformBlockIndex;

            GL.GetActiveUniformBlock(ProgramId, 0, ActiveUniformBlockParameter.UniformBlockBinding,
                                     out uniformBlockIndex);
            GL.GetProgram(ProgramId, ProgramParameter.ActiveUniformBlocks, out activeUniformBlocks);
            GL.GetInteger(GetPName.MaxUniformBlockSize, out maxSizeMaterialUniformBuffer);


            uniformInstancesPerBlock = maxSizeMaterialUniformBuffer/sizeMaterialBlock;
            numberOfBlocks =
                (int) Math.Ceiling(((double) sizeUniformInstance/uniformInstancesPerBlock*sizeMaterialBlock));
            mtlBuffer = new byte[maxSizeMaterialUniformBuffer];

            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeMaterialBlock);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(block, buffer, false);
            for (int i = 0; i < uniformInstancesPerBlock; i++) {
                Marshal.Copy(buffer, mtlBuffer, i*sizeMaterialBlock, sizeMaterialBlock);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out _iUniform);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.UniformBuffer, _iUniform);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.UniformBuffer, new IntPtr(sizeMaterialBlock), mtlBuffer,
                          BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);


        }
```

I was wondering if there was a more dynamic way to hold the uniform information, without having to use System.Reflection to create the structure on demand. When I did the fragment and vertex shaders I was able to use a string, and then GL.CreateShader() and GL.ShaderSource. The only thin I can think of is that ShaderType.GeometryShader is actually the Uniform shader and it is label differently.

Any methods would be appreciated, even if it means doing it completely different. If I have left out any information, I apologise, and will try to add it on request.

Comment: I am confused by many things in this question. I don't understand how you can call glBufferData before binding the buffer object with glBindBuffer. The text after your code talks about shader creation, but that has very little to do with uniform blocks. Ultimately, OpenGL was designed for C and C++, not managed C#. It's a pretty low-level API, so many parts of it will require interactions that are not natural for C#.

Comment: The glBindBuffer/BufferData mix up is a small mistake on my part. I guess a better question would have been, "What are all the ways to create a uniform object?". As I don't want to have to have that hardcoded structure.  (Making the change in provided code to reflect buffer/bind mixup).

Comment: "ShaderType.GeometryShader is actually the Uniform shader", huh? What's that mean? No, geometry shader is not another term for uniform shader, what is a uniform shader anyway?

Answer (score 0):

> What are all the ways to create a uniform object?

There is no such thing as a "uniform object". There are only buffer objects, which can be used to store uniform data. They can also be used to store vertex data, pixel data, and various other stuff. But they're all the same object type: buffer object. And you create them all the same way.

The ways to supply data to a buffer object are fairly simple. glBuffer(Sub)Data, and glMapBuffer(Range). Your problem isn't with the interface so much as C#, which is not a native API. So you have to jump through hoops to upload your data.

Honestly, I would suggest using a little C++/CLI as an interface for handling your buffer object data uploading. It easier and less verbose to deal with data in native objects than in managed ones.